# Why is my application state updating without change event from store - flux

Tags: reactjs, state, flux

TL;DR

Here's a video of me explaining (poorly) the issue: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJogEfYYHRo&feature=youtu.be

I'm making a chat feature on a web application using flux.
I have a store with an array called messages. As is expected with flux whenever there is a change to the store, the store emits a change event and a listener on the view hears it and updates the state using a getter method from the store.

In this application I want to load some initial messages ( to imitate grabbing a history of messages from a database ). For some reason however, whenever I set the state on my view to the store getter ( which returns the array of messages ) it continues to update whenever a new message is pushed to the messages array in the store, which it shouldn't. It should only update when a change event is broadcasted. Why is this the case?

Here's The **View** & All Relevant Code

```
class ChatBar extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // CHAT FUNCTIONS
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        chat__messages: [],
        chat__playercount: 0,
        chat__message_input: "",
    };
}

// ====================================================

componentDidMount(){
    ChatStore.on(CHANGE, this._onChange);
    ChatStore.init();    
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    ChatStore.removeListener(CHANGE);
}

_onChange() {
    // IN THE FUTURE NEED TO CHANGE THIS TO 
    // RETURN ENTIRE STATE, NOT JUST MESSAGES
    this.setState({chat__messages: ChatStore.getMessages()});
}

// HANDLING OF FORMS, DATA SUBMISSION ECT
// =====================================================
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({chat__message_input: e.target.value});
}

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (this.state.chat__message_input == "") {
        // create some error here later
        return
    };

    ChatActions.addMessage({
        username: "username",
        message: this.state.chat__message_input,
        message_id: uid("msg-"),
    });  

    // reset input field
    this.setState({chat__message_input: ""});
}
...
```

Here's the **Store**

```
var CHANGE = "change_event";

class ChatStoreClass extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this._messages = [
            {
                username: "christian",
                message: "hello world",
                message_id: "msg-12kjds8",
            }
        ];
    }  

    init() {
        this._emitChange();
    }

    getMessages() {
        return this._messages;
    }

    _emitChange() {
        this.emit(CHANGE);
    }


}

var ChatStore = new ChatStoreClass;

AppDispatcher.register(function(payload){
    switch(payload.actionType) {
        case ChatConstants.ADD_MESSAGE:
            ChatStore._messages.push(payload.action);
            break;
    }
})

export default ChatStore;
```

ChatStore._messages.push(payload.action); 
is updating the state on the view without a change event being emitted :(

Apologies if poorly explained. I'm not one to usually explain my programming issues to other people let alone anyone.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Is `_emitChange()` getting called when a new message is pushed or is the state updated by some other mechanism?

Comment: _emitChange() is not being called when a new message is pushed. I don't know what is updating the state.

Comment: Is it possible that your component is being mounted multiple times (maybe try a `console.log('mount')` in `componentDidMount`)?  This would trigger multiple init events on your store. – on second thought, that's inconsistent with your prior answer.  How about placing a `console.trace()` in `_onChange()` to get the stack trace ... you might be able to infer where the event is being generated.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response again, I tried logging "mount" in componentDidMount for hell of it anyways, and well... didn't work. Just logged "mount" once, as you would expect.

As for the console.trace(), I placed it various places and followed the stack. Nothing that I could point out as responsible.

This is driving me crazy.
I put the console.trace() in _onChange() but there wasn't really much point, as the problem is that the state is updating without me even needing to broadcast a change event.

Comment: If I were to type:

this.state = {
    chat__messages: ChatStore._messages,
}

and then were to update the _messages array in the store, the state on the view would update on its own.

It's infuriating.

Comment: No prob - happy to try :-).  Is your `ChatBar` receiving props from a parent component that could be changing them at unexpected times?  That could definitely cause unexpected updates.  Not likely to reflect your updated messages though.

Comment: Nope, CharBar isn't receiving any props.

uploaded a vid of me explaining the issue if that helps:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJogEfYYHRo&feature=youtu.be

i am british, mumble like a motherfu*cker and suck at explaining stuff, so bare with me :')

Comment: The video was definitely helpful and totally coherent.  I hadn't appreciated how you were interacting with the chat text submit mechanism.  Have you looked at redux.js at all as a possible replacement for you flux/EventEmitter?   I've been using it extensively with react-redux and redux-thunk on both web apps and React Native.  I think you'd benefit a lot.  It's *fluxish*, and forces you to work with immutable types past to components through props.  It sort of enforces a lot of React best practices in a reliable, elegant way.

Comment: I haven't given redux much look, my only understanding of it is that, as you say, its quite similar to flux.

Will definitely look into it
thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getMessages()` is returning a *reference* to the message list in the store rather than the messages themselves.  `SetState` (e.g. in your `handleSubmit`) always triggers an update to the component; because you've set `this.state.chat__messages` to a reference to the store's message list (rather adding its messages to your `chat_messages` array), it's always up-to-date with the store.

```
getMessages() {
    return [...this._messages]; // or w/o ES6 -> return Array.apply([], this._messages)
}
```

Should give you the effect you expect.

I'm sure this was unintended, but part of the confusion is that you're never supposed to mutate state unless through `SetState`.  By using a reference to mutable data, you get an unexpected effect that's pretty tricky to track down.

Comment: oh man, thank you so much. That had been driving me crazy for the last few days.

Thank you for taking the time to help me, I seriously appreciate it.

Comment: Happy to help, @ChristianL - enjoyed the puzzle... and have been down many related roads before.  BTW, do "accept" this if it answers your question.  Cheers!